# MongoDB - Updating subdocument

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working with mongo 3.4.13 and I want to add an element in this document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5981d38cf43047f3235febbc"), 
    "code" : "A0001", 
    "subItems": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5981d38cf43047f3235febbc"), 
            "code" : "A1001", 
            "subItems": []
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5981d38cf43047f3235febbc"), 
            "code" : "A2001", 
            "subItems": [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5981d38cf43047f3235febbc"), 
                    "code" : "A2101", 
                    "subItems": [
                        //I wanna add an element here
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

But I have no idea how to do it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question I assume that you need to add an  element into subItems array field belonging to BSON Document as mentioned above.

$addToSet operator is used to append a value into an array field as a part of update operation only if value does not exist into an array thereby ensuring uniqueness of values into an array field.

Comment: Do you have any example? I've never used that operator